# Magento: How do I cache module output?

Tags: magento

I have seen the wiki page on how to cache block output on Magentocommerce.com and read an inchoo article on how to do it. However, I want to cache the output of a module that isn't tied into a product.

What my module does is load up the colour entries in an attribute, does some maths on them to sort them by tint/hue/brightness etc. and then outputs a colour picker (that can be used on product pages).

I have other modules that could also benefit from cache control, again these are not particularly tied to a product. Hence, in the tutorials, where there is this:

`'cache_tags'     => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG),`
`'cache_key'      => $this->getProduct()->getId()`

do I just stuff in any old numbers?

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-block-caching/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use custom cache tag and key

```
'cache_tags'     => array(Yourpackage_Yourmodule_Model_Yourmodel::CACHE_TAG) 
'cache_key'      => '<your cache key here>'
```

If I got you right, your block output is always the same, that's why you can use attribute code as cache tag and attribute id as key (for example).

Comment: Thankyou. I am getting my unique key in the memcache output so all seems well:


>30 END
<30 get alphanumericPINKXYLOPHONES
>30 sending key alphanumericPINKXYLOPHONES
>30 END

I had to put a new 'construct' statement in 'Block' for the output to get cached, I also had to put in the predefined 'CACHE_TAG' constant in 'Model'. I don't think the 'cache-key' was really needed, but it is cache-ing!